# Python infinite loop after aborting

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class LogDigger:

    @staticmethod
    def RunInfiniteLoopSyslog():
        while True:
            line = LogDigger.syslog_p.stdout.readline()
            Utils.log("New line in syslog: %s" % line.rstrip('\n'))

    @staticmethod
    def RunInfiniteLoopXlog():
        while True:
            line = LogDigger.xlog_p.stdout.readline()
            Utils.log("New line in xlog: %s" % line.rstrip('\n'))

    @staticmethod
    def StartProcesses():

        LogDigger.syslog_p = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-f', '-n0', '/var/log/syslog'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        LogDigger.xlog_p = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-f', '-n0', '/var/log/mail-xlog'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

        syslog_thread = threading.Thread(target = LogDigger.RunInfiniteLoopSyslog)
        xlog_thread = threading.Thread(target = LogDigger.RunInfiniteLoopXlog)

        syslog_thread.start()
        xlog_thread.start()
```

The problem is, when I press ctrl+c to abort the program, it instantly jumps into infinite loop of "New line in xlog/syslog". Do you see the problem ? :/ I need add some code, which aborts also those two threads maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what Fantasizer has said, try the code below:

```
while True:
    try:
        print('running')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('stop')
        exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module to handle SIGINT and others in a more graceful way

Answer (score 0):

With a ctrl+c, python raises a `KeyboardInterrupt`, so you could catch that and break your while loops.