# RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am making a Python 3 app that has a prompt where the user enters commands. I'm running Python 3.5 on macOS Sierra.

I'm trying to prevent exiting with `Ctrl+C` and having users exit instead by simply typing `exit` into the prompt.

I am doing this using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6019460/7450368

However, when prompting the user again, I get `RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline`.

Is there a way I can fix this?

**Here's my code:**

```
import interpret
import signal
def SigIntHand(SIG, FRM):
    print("\nUse 'exit' to exit.")
    prompt()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, SigIntHand)




version = ("v0.0.3")




class CommandError(Exception):
    pass




def prompt():
    try:
        task = input("Einstein " + version + "  > ")
    except RuntimeError:
        task = input("Einstein " + version + "  > ")
    try:
        execute(task)
    except CommandError as e:
        print(e)
    prompt()


def execute(command):
    command = command.lower()
    interpret.interpret(command)

prompt()
```

`interpret.interpret("command")` is called by `main.py` to execute the command `command` if it exists.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting to throw the runtime error in the first try-except of `prompt`?

Comment: I don't expect anything to cause it, but it happens nonetheless. I just get `RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline`.

Comment: The user pressing `Ctrl+C` triggers it, but I'm not sure why. Adding a `try`...`except` allows it to be caught once, but if the user presses `Ctrl+C` again, the same error pops up.

Comment: I can't reproduce by replacing `interpret.interpret` with `os.system` which is sort of what I was expecting you to be doing, could you try to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Your control flow looks a bit strange. To handle the user pressing `Ctrl+C` more than once, you should use a loop to keep asking for input.

Also, you can catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` in Python which gets raised every time you hit `Ctrl+C`. It's a bit easier than messing with signal handlers.

```
version = ("v0.0.3")

class CommandError(Exception):
    pass

def prompt():
    try:
        return input("Einstein " + version + "  > ")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('') # Go to the next line so printing looks better.
        return None

def force_prompt():
    task = None
    while task is None:
        task = prompt()
    return task

def get_and_execute_command():
    task = force_prompt()
    try:
        execute(task)
    except CommandError as e:
        print(e)

def execute(command):
    command = command.lower()
    print('Command: %s' % command)

get_and_execute_command()
```

Comment: The reason I don't catch `KeyboardInterrupt` is that (for me at least) it doesn't prevent the user exiting with `Ctrl+C` - I can `print` out 'Exit with 'exit' next time!` but it still exits after that.